# Pair of functions $F(x)$ (transcendental),$A(x)$ (algebraic) with expanded series of positive integer coefficient linked by derivative

Tags: complex-analysis, reference-request, special-functions, examples-counterexamples

$$F(x)=\sum_0^{\infty}b_k x^k,b_k\in \mathcal{N} \bigcup 0,\exists M \space b_k \leq M^k$$.
$$A(x)=\sum_0^{\infty}a_k x^k,a_k\in \mathcal{N} \bigcup 0,\exists M \space a_k \leq L^k$$

where $F(x)$ is transcendental function of of Riemann surface,$A(x)$ is algebraic function of Riemann surface.

Question:are there pair of functions $F(x),A(x)$ such that $$A(x)= x \frac{dF(x)}{dx}$$

Further,$F(x)$ with what property ,or $A(x)$ with what property,is $$A(x)= x \frac{dF(x)}{dx}$$ valid?

Comment: The equivalent condition $F'(x) = \frac{A(x)}{x}$ avoids integration limits (and turns into $a_i = i b_i$ for all $i$).

Comment: @Winther,thanks,I have edited the post

Comment: I guess,there is no pair of such functions.If $F(x)$ is a lacunary series,there is no such a pair of functions,but I am not sure if there is  such a pair of function in other cases

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your question is  on the generalisation of the following result by Polya (J fur die reine angwt math, 1921): " Let $F\in \mathbb{Z}[[x]]$ with non zero radius of convergence and suppose that $xF^{\prime}(x)$ is a rational function, then $F$ is a rational function" obtained by replacing the word "rational" by "algebraic", then I think that this is proved in Yves Andr\'e's book "G-functions and Geometry".

Comment: You mean " Let $F\in \mathbb{Z}[[x]]$ with non zero radius of convergence and suppose that $xF^{\prime}(x)$ is an algebraic function, then $F$ is an algebraic function" has been proved in Yves Andr\'e's book "G-functions and Geometry"?Then there is no pair function $A(x),F(x)$linked by derivative or integral.Strangely,it is contradict to our intuition.

Comment: This is the condition that the coefficients of $F$ are in $\mathbb{Z}$ that is very important. Think of $-\log(1-x)=F(x)$, that is not algebraic or rational, but $xF^{\prime}(x)$ is rational hence algebraic.